# How to wrap "<pre>" tag around whitespaces in a java String?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a long java String , I need to wrap all whitespaces (length >=2) with `<pre></pre>` tag... , How to achieve that ?

ex :

```
before :
String str = "<font color=\"#000000\">A B  C   D</font>"

after :
<font color=\"#000000\">A B<pre>  </pre>C<pre>   </pre>D</font>

Between A and B is one whitespace , and not wrapped.
Between B and C is two whitespaces , and it is wrapped.
Between C and D is three whitespaces , and it is wrapped,too.
```

How to achieve that in RegExp ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: How about `<font   color="#000000"></font>`?

Comment: Why do you need to care about the number of spaces?

Comment: @KennyTM , `<font      color="#000000"></font>` will be skipped , not wrapped.

Comment: Could you replace white space with "&nbsp;" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a CSS solution using [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop):

```
white-space: pre
```

With this sequences of white space are not collapsed. So:

```
<font color="#000000" style="white-space:pre">A B  C   D</font>
```

Comment: Thank you ... but ... How to add this attribute to each `<font>` tag ?

Comment: Thank you , I solve this not by regex :
`str.replaceAll("<font", "<font style=\"white-space:pre\""));`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually, font tags are an evil relic from the 90s. you should also do `str = str.replaceAll("(<\\/?)font([^>]*>)", "$1span$2")` to convert all font tags to span tags.

Comment: @seanizer: But they are not as evil as trying to parse HTML with a regular expression!

Answer (score 1):

That will probably not do what you want... Will a `&nbsp;` do the job you want? Also, I'd seriously consider replacing spacing with `<span style="width: 10px; display: inline-block;"> </span>`. Or even a proper table...

Answer (score 1):

why don't you simply set `white-space:pre-wrap` or `white-space:pre` as css for the element containing your string? i think this is what you're trying to archive.

(or, even more easy, use `&nbsp;` instead of ' ' (normal space))

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "123 123  123";
    s = s.replaceAll("(  )+", "<pre>$1</pre>");
```

The String s then contains `123 123<pre>  </pre>123`